# Finding the minimum of the directional derivative of $f(x,y)=x\cos(2y)+2$ along a level curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

A particle moves along the surface given by

$$f(x, y)= x \cos(2y)+2,$$

such that its coordinates are determined by the curve

$$\mathbf{r}(t)= \langle\,\ln(t +1),\sin(\pi\cdot t)\,\rangle,$$

for $0 \le t \le 2$. At the moment when $t = \frac{1}{4}$, the particle arrives at point $E$ shown on the surface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utt5A.png)

How do you find the minimum value of the directional derivative of $f$ at $E$?

I am having difficulty relating the $\mathbf{r}$ function with the $f$ function. Is it that $\mathbf{r}$ is just a level curve of $f$?

Comment: The question makes no sense. Are we talking about the surface  z=xcos(2y)+2 in 3-space? If so, how is that related to the given parameric curve in 2-space?

Comment: Yes, the question above is asking about the surface in 3 space (as per the image). I believe that the given parametric curve in 2-space is a level curve of the z function. If I'm not mistaken, could I input the known t-value into the r(t) function, solve for x and y respectively and use both values to find the negative gradient of f (negative because that is the minimum value). Then, take the derivative of r(t), plug in the known t value, and then find the dot product between the gradient and the r(t) derivatives?